# Select only United State Time Zones

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, timezone

Is there an easy way to create a list of only the time zones in US?

I am using this code but it produces every time zone and I only want `Pacific`, `Central`, `Mountain`, and `Eastern`

```
List<TimeZoneInfo> _timeZones = TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones().ToList();
```

Comment: So add a `.Where` and list out the time zones you want.

Comment: Are you asking how to add 4 items to a list? OR you want some fancy LINQ query to do that?

Comment: Aren't you forgetting Puerto Rico in Atlantic timezone?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There's little point trying to drink from the fire hose here.  Just ask for the ones you want explicitly:

```
        var zones = new List<TimeZoneInfo> {
            TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Pacific Standard Time"),
            TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Mountain Standard Time"),
            TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central Standard Time"),
            TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time")
        };
```

Don't forget Hawaii and Alaska :)

Comment: Don't forget Puerto Rico in `Atlantic`.

Answer (score 4):

Well you *could* just filter them by ID using exactly the criteria you've described:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var inclusions = new[] { "Pacific", "Central", "Mountain", "Eastern" };
        foreach (var zone in TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones()
                      .Where(zone => inclusions.Any(x => zone.Id.Contains(x))))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(zone.Id);
        }
    }
}
```

However, that gets the following list:

```
Pacific Standard Time (Mexico)
Pacific Standard Time
US Mountain Standard Time
Mountain Standard Time (Mexico)
Mountain Standard Time
Central America Standard Time
Central Standard Time
Central Standard Time (Mexico)
Canada Central Standard Time
SA Pacific Standard Time
Eastern Standard Time
US Eastern Standard Time
Central Brazilian Standard Time
Pacific SA Standard Time
SA Eastern Standard Time
Central Europe Standard Time
Central European Standard Time
W. Central Africa Standard Time
Central Asia Standard Time
N. Central Asia Standard Time
AUS Central Standard Time
AUS Eastern Standard Time
West Pacific Standard Time
Central Pacific Standard Time
```

... which is obviously not quite what you want.

If you only want a *specific* set of time zones, you're probably best just hard-coding the IDs of the ones you want, using [`TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(id)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.findsystemtimezonebyid.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

I think this is an updated list of US timezones:

```
var timezones = new List<TimeZoneInfo> {
    TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Pacific Standard Time"),
    TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Mountain Standard Time"),
    TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central Standard Time"),
    TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time"),
    TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("US Eastern Standard Time"),
    TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("US Mountain Standard Time"),            
    TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Hawaiian Standard Time"),
    TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Alaskan Standard Time"),
    TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Pacific Standard Time (Mexico)"),
    TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central Standard Time (Mexico)"),
    TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("UTC")
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I created a list of US time zones:

```
   var zones = new List<TimeZoneInfo> {
    TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Pacific Standard Time"),
    TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Mountain Standard Time"),
    TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central Standard Time"),
    TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time"),
    TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("US Eastern Standard Time"),
    TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("US Mountain Standard Time"),            
    TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Hawaiian Standard Time"),
    TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Alaskan Standard Time"),
};
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
var _timeZones = TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones().ToList().Where(zone=>zone.DisplayName.Contains("US"));
```

Comment: you will miss US tie zones that doesn't have US in DisplayName, but still a US time zone

Comment: Filters out Arizona.

Answer (score 0):

###### Getting All of US With Territories

Finding a timezone by a numeric value of `BaseUtcOffset.Hours` would be the better scenario, for the timezone names may change, but the number of zones will not. I've also taken the answer to mean US, with Hawaii and the Aluetian islands, and the territories of Puerto Rico, Guam and Samoa.

###### Filtering out Non US Zones

Step 2 of the process is to keep the ones which are actually used within the US/territories and we will use a *positive* search to get those zone names to shorten the list. Generally we can filter those out between "{Name}Time" where the name is at the start of the string and the literal "Time" is at the end.

###### Final removal of selections within zones but outside US

Finally, since the list will at this point have locations that are non-us but within the valid time zones, the below code will do a negative removal process to return the final needed list.

```
var positivePattern = 
 @"^(Atlantic|Alaskan|Central|Eastern|Mountain|Pacific|Hawaii|Aleutian|West\sPacific)[^T]+Time";
var ignorePattern = @"(?=.*(Brazilian|SA|Mexico|Central\sAmerica))";
List<int> UsAndTerritoryTimeZones = new List<int> { -4, -5, -6, -7, -8, -9, -10, -11, 10, 11 };


TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones()
            .Where(tz => UsAndTerritoryTimeZones.Contains(tz.BaseUtcOffset.Hours))
        //  .Where(tz => tz.HasIanaId == false)
            .Where(tz => Regex.IsMatch(tz.StandardName, positivePattern))
            .Where(tz => !Regex.IsMatch(tz.StandardName, ignorePattern))
            .OrderByDescending(tz => tz.BaseUtcOffset)
            .ToList()
```

---

##### Result

| Id | DisplayName | StandardName | DaylightName | BaseUtcOffset | SupportsDaylightSavingTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Central Pacific Standard Time | "(UTC+11:00) Solomon Is., New Caledonia" | Central Pacific Standard Time | Central Pacific Daylight Time | 11:00:00 | FALSE |
| West Pacific Standard Time | "(UTC+10:00) Guam, Port Moresby" | West Pacific Standard Time | West Pacific Daylight Time | 10:00:00 | FALSE |
| Atlantic Standard Time | (UTC-04:00) Atlantic Time (Canada) | Atlantic Standard Time | Atlantic Daylight Time | -04:00:00 | TRUE |
| Eastern Standard Time | (UTC-05:00) Eastern Time (US & Canada) | Eastern Standard Time | Eastern Daylight Time | -05:00:00 | TRUE |
| Central Standard Time | (UTC-06:00) Central Time (US & Canada) | Central Standard Time | Central Daylight Time | -06:00:00 | TRUE |
| Mountain Standard Time | (UTC-07:00) Mountain Time (US & Canada) | Mountain Standard Time | Mountain Daylight Time | -07:00:00 | TRUE |
| Pacific Standard Time | (UTC-08:00) Pacific Time (US & Canada) | Pacific Standard Time | Pacific Daylight Time | -08:00:00 | TRUE |
| Alaskan Standard Time | (UTC-09:00) Alaska | Alaskan Standard Time | Alaskan Daylight Time | -09:00:00 | TRUE |
| Aleutian Standard Time | (UTC-10:00) Aleutian Islands | Aleutian Standard Time | Aleutian Daylight Time | -10:00:00 | TRUE |
| Hawaiian Standard Time | (UTC-10:00) Hawaii | Hawaiian Standard Time | Hawaiian Daylight Time | -10:00:00 | FALSE |